# VBA to copy and rename file that user choose in dialog

Tags: vba, userform

I need this VBA macro that lets the user choose a PDF file from their own folder and then the macro should copy the PDF to a fixed folder destination and rename the file based on two values chosen in ComboBoxes.

I have tried the following code, but fails at the last sentence. Anybody who can help me?

```
Sub add_testrepport()
   Dim intChoice As Integer
   Dim strPath As String

   'allow the user to select one file
   Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False

   'make the file dialog visible to the user
   intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show

   'determine what choice the user made
   If intChoice <> 0 Then

      'get the file path selected by the user
       strPath = Application.FileDialog( _
         msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)

      'copy the file path to filecopy
      FileCopy strPath, "K:\05_RAP\Klement\Test"
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: While searching a lot, what code have you found? Did you try to run it? What happened?

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat old, but if you're still looking for an answer, is it as simple as removing the underscore and space from in front of `msoFileDialogOpen` ?  When I copied and pasted into Excel, it wouldn't compile initially; but after correcting that, it ran fine. That is, it copied a file, naming it `Test` (no extension) in the `K:\05_RAP\Klement\` folder I created.

If you intended for Test to be a folder with the original filename of the file, you might try this code (leave 2 lines blank, then indent 4 spaces to post code in StackOverflow):

```
Sub add_testrepport()

Dim intChoice As Integer
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFName As String

'allow the user to select one file
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False

'make the file dialog visible to the user
intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show

'determine what choice the user made
If intChoice <> 0 Then

    'get the file path selected by the user
    strPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)

    ' get file name from path
    strFName = Mid(strPath, InStrRev(strPath, "\") + 1, Len(strPath))

    'copy the file path to filecopy
    FileCopy strPath, "K:\05_RAP\Klement\Test\" & strFName

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so your desired steps are:

- [Choose a file](https://www.google.at/search?safe=off&q=excel+vba+file+chooser&oq=excel+vba+file+chooser&gs_l=serp.3..0i7i30k1j0l2j0i8i30k1.25811.25811.0.26351.1.1.0.0.0.0.75.75.1.1.0....0...1.1.64.serp..0.1.74.6542BUwMuoo)
- [Copy that file](https://www.google.at/search?safe=off&q=excel+vba+copy+file+from+one+folder+to+another&oq=excel+vba+copy+file+&gs_l=serp.3.0.0i20k1l2j0l8.72247.73997.0.75193.10.10.0.0.0.0.92.824.10.10.0....0...1.1.64.serp..0.10.822.cCgArV38s4c)
- [Rename that file](https://www.google.at/search?safe=off&q=excel+vba+rename+file&oq=excel+vba+rename+&gs_l=serp.3.1.0i20k1l2j0l8.35099.35897.0.37650.7.7.0.0.0.0.86.484.6.6.0....0...1.1.64.serp..1.6.483...35i39k1.a2RMmSZ1-S0)
  based on [combo boxes](https://www.google.at/search?safe=off&q=excel+vba+combo+boxes&oq=excel+vba+combo+boxes&gs_l=serp.3..0i22i30k1j0i22i10i30k1l9.35367.37411.0.37569.11.11.0.0.0.0.122.1005.9j2.11.0....0...1.1.64.serp..0.11.999...0j35i39k1j0i67k1j0i20k1j0i10k1j0i13k1.TL4BxrT6bf0).

If you encounter any specific problem with any of the code, update your question accordingly to get a specific answer.

Comment: Hi david, Thank you for your answer and quick reply! 
I know the steps of the code, and understand the individual bits of it, but as i mentioned I'm quit new and therefore not able to se how i combine the individual steps.

Comment: I see. Edit your question and post your "individual steps", tell us if they work and what you tried to combine them. I am sure that we can help you with that.